# Calling methods from different classes with the class name

Tags: java, reflection, singleton

I have various classes with singleton pattern. They all are extending from an abstract class. Each class has a getInstance() method (with exact same name). I want to get instance with the class name (String). For example

```
public abstract class AbsCls {
}
```

---

```
public class A extends AbsCls {
  private static A a;
  private A() {
}
public synchronized static A getInstance() {
  if(a==null) {
    a == new A();
  }
  return a;
}
```

---

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AbsCls[] array = new AbsCls[5];
    array[0]=neededFunction("A");
    array[1]=neededFunction("B");
  }
}
```

All the classes have the same structure with class A. How should be the neededFunction()?

I can write "if.. else", but i feel like there should be a more elegant way. Thanks for any help in advance...

Comment: I would recommend you to read about and implement the Visitor design pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the full class name as in `package.ClassName`, reflection, and `Class.forName(theName)`.

For instance with a `String` object:

```
try {
    String newString = (String)Class.forName("java.lang.String").newInstance();
}
catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
    // TODO handle
}
catch (InstantiationException ie) {
    // TODO handle
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
    // TODO handle
}
```

So your method could roughly look like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T getInstance(String clazz) {
    // TODO check for clazz null
    try {
        return (T)Class.forName(clazz).getMethod("getInstance", (Class<?>[])null).invoke(null, (Object[])null);
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        // TODO handle
        return null;
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
        // TODO handle
        return null;
    }
    catch (InvocationTargetException ite) {
        // TODO handle
        return null;
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
        // TODO handle
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Edit** for OP:

The `(Class<?>[])null` and `(Object[])null` are `null` arguments cast as their expected type.

Basically:

- the `getMethod` method of `Class` takes a `String` representing the method's name, and a varargs of `Class<?>` representing its parameter types. The method we call (`getInstance`) takes no arguments, therefore the argument to `getMethod` is null, but we want to cast it as the expected argument. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class...%29).
- the `invoke` method of `Method` takes an `Object` as the target instance to invoke the method against (in our case, `null` since it's a class method) and a varargs of `Object` as the arguments. But again, your `getInstance` method takes no arguments, so we use `null` and cast it as an array of `Object`. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Comment: But because of the singleton pattern, constructors of A, B, C... classes are private. So newInstance() method does not work. I use A.getInstance() to create an object...

Comment: It did the trick. Thanks a lot. But if you can explain "(Class<?>[])null" and "(Object[])null" when you have time, it'ld be appreciated...

Comment: @s.alem You're welcome :) I will comment on those parameters in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
AbsCls[] array = new AbsCls[5]; // this create object for AbsCls
 array[0]=neededFunction("A"); // calling method from AbsCls
array[1]=neededFunction("B");// calling method from AbsCls
```

If you create object for super class you cant get method from sub classes

```
 AbsCls[] array = new A[5]; //this create object for A
```

You access both classes if you want to call super class method user `super` keyword

```
    array[0]=neededFunction("A"); //// calling method from A
    array[1]=super.neededFunction("B");//// calling method from AbsCls
```